# Regular Expression in vb script

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am using the below RegEx to match numbers meeting any of the following conditions:

1. 10 digits starting with a "9"
2. 8 digits starting with a "9"
3. 10 digits starting with a "6"

Conditions 1 and 2 work fine, but condition 3 doesn't work. Please help.

```
((\D)(9[0-9]{7})|(9[0-9]{9}) | (6[0-9]{9}) )[\.\s\)\n\r\:\[\]\,}{]
```

Comment: You should publish a small but representative set of inputs that you want (not) to match.

Answer (score 0):

What's the significance of all the extra garbage and the trailing spaces?

The following should work for your criteria:

```
\b9[0-9]{9}\b|\b9[0-9]{7}\b|\b6[0-9]{9}\b
```

Specifying a *word boundary* ensures that the match is not a part of a larger number.

Comment: [\.\s\)\n\r\:\[\]\,}{]  - sometimes the data can be as below 9123456789],9123456789 ,9123456789}.Hence the extra garbage is required.

Comment: No luck, its not working with \b9[0-9]{9}\b|\b9[0-9]{7}\b|\b6[0-9]{9}\b

Comment: Works for me, even with your test string: `9123456789],9123456789 ,9123456789}`. Perhaps it's *your implementation* of the RegEx that's failing. Edit the original question to show us how you're using it.